# angujar js 2 Owl Carousel Responsive options not working

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

i am using Angular 2
i want to make it responsive carousel

```
<owl-carousel [options]="{nav : true, slideBy : 2 ,margin :14  }"


</owl-carousel>
```

this is working fine without responsive

but when i want to add responsive options in  its shows me error

but when i add Responsive code in options is show error

but at a time of run Project Browser show this Below error
can any one help me out ,to create  Responsive ng2-owl-carousel
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-xs-12">
          <owl-carousel [options]="{responsive:{
    '320':{
        items:1

    },
    '600':{
        items:3

    },
     '980':{
        items:4,
       nav:true,
      dots: true

    }

  }}" [items]="viewCustomObjectList" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe little bit explanation of code will make it easier for future users. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add options on class for example i added one slider option on home.compnent.ts like this

```
 public sliderOPT: any ={nav:true,dots:false,loop:true,autoPlay:true,autoPlayTimeout:5000,autoplayHoverPause:true,items:4,
    navText: this.arrow,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive: {
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }

}
```

and call it on owl carousel tag (options attribute)

```
<owl-carousel  
[options]="sliderOPT"
[carouselClasses]="['owl-theme','offer_box','mainSlider1', 'row', 'sliding']">
*
*
*
</owl-carousel>
```

Answer (score -2):

This should be the JSON structure as it is a string you have to differentiate the items with quotes

```
{
  responsive:{
    '320':{
        items:1

    },
    '720':{
        items:3

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer in English please, Spanish discussion should be kept to [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com)